# How to Split the string with multiple characters in C#?

Tags: c#, regex, string, split

I have a string here : **Name_20160204_102-10002**
I want it to be spited into 4 pieces like

```
str[0] = "Name";
str[1] = "20160204";
str[2] = "102";
str[3] = "10002";
```

I'm really poor in regular expression if anyone know how to solve please kindly let me know

Comment: What have you tried so far? People are more likely to help if you show that you have tried to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: I've tried to use str.Split('_'); but I don't really know how to split with multiple characters. However, now it works perfectly fine. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`string.Split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) and pass it an array of characters to split on.

```
"Name_20160204_102-10002".Split(new char[] {'_', '-'});
```

Which gives the output:

```
["Name",
"20160204",
"102",
"10002"]
```

Comment: @Zac: please don't answer obvious duplicates. It just encourages laziness on the part of questioners.